# How to encode a unicode character in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, unicode, fs

I'm using NodeJS to read a series of keys and values from a spreadsheet to build a JSON object, and then writing that object to a file, e.g. **|** key    **|** value **|** becomes the object {"key": "value"}

I'm using JSON.stringify to convert the objects to strings, and then writing this string to a file

```
fs.writeFileSync('object.json', JSON.stringify(object, null, 2));
```

The spreadsheet contains some unicode characters, which need to be stored as their encoded value, e.g. é as \u00E9, which is not handled by the snippet above.

How can I encode unicode characters in the file so, for example, "Numéro" is stored as "Num\u00E9ro"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a plugin to encode your char string, or you can do it by hand with a simple regex :

```
exports.unicodeAccent = function(str)
{
var charset = [
    "€",
    "À",
    "Á",
    "Â",
    "Ã",
    "Ä",
    "Å",
    "à",
    "á",
    "â",
    "ã",
    "ä",
    "å",
    "Ò",
    "Ó",
    "Ô",
    "Õ",
    "Õ",
    "Ö",
    "Ø",
    "ò",
    "ó",
    "ô",
    "õ",
    "ö",
    "ø",
    "È",
    "É",
    "Ê",
    "Ë",
    "è",
    "é",
    "ê",
    "ë",
    "ð",
    "Ç",
    "ç",
    "Ð",
    "Ì",
    "Í",
    "Î",
    "Ï",
    "ì",
    "í",
    "î",
    "ï",
    "Ù",
    "Ú",
    "Û",
    "Ü",
    "ù",
    "ú",
    "û",
    "ü",
    "Ñ",
    "ñ",
    "Š",
    "š",
    "Ÿ",
    "ÿ",
    "ý",
    "Ž",
    "ž"
];

for(var i = 0; i < charset.length; i++)
{
    var code        = ("00000000"+(charset[i].charCodeAt(0).toString(16))).slice(-4);
    var unicodeStr  = "\\u"+code;

    var re  = new RegExp(charset[i], "gm");
    str = str.replace(re, unicodeStr);

}

return str;

}
```

Comment: thanks, working great!
Only problem is the \u is being stored as "\\u" in the output JSON files